# Record tracked changes in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a series of spread sheets calculating percentage increases in performance for different subject areas.

Is there a way of record and track the data as it changes, new data overwrites previous data and I would like all of the data changes to be recorded on a different sheet so that these changes can be used to automatically update a tracking chart.

The data that I want to track and record changes to are in cells D16 -P16.

D33 - P33

D52 - P52

I have found a VBA code else where on this forum that sounds like it ought to work, but it is for data in a column not a row, and being a total novice at this I really don't know how to adjust it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 12)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:G12")) Is Nothing Then
        r = Target.Row
        For c = 1 To 12
            arr(1, c) = Cells(r, c).Value
        Next
        With shtLog
            .Range(.Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 12)) = arr
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this VBA code will help to record the changes in particular sheet.**

```
Dim PreviousValue

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A , C:C")) Is Nothing Then

    Sheets("ChangeLog").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
      Application.UserName & " Chang in cell " & Target.Address _
       & " From " & PreviousValue & " To " & Target.Value
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
PreviousValue = Target.Value
End Sub
```

**NB:** Change the Column name as per your need.

*I do hope this help you.*

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have put this into a test sheet, so I can work out how to apply it, using the cells A16:E16 as the cells I want to track and record data changes from.  But VB is returning 'run time error 9: script out of range' and when I click 'debug' it highlights the three lines before 'End If',  from the line starting with:       Sheets("ChangeLog")...............

Comment: You need to Insert a sheet and name it ChangeLog or Rename  any existing Sheet. And Replace Range("A:A, C:C") with Range("A16:E16"). Suppose you want to use entire A to E  then use Range("A:A ,  E:E" ),, if want to test only Row 16 then Range("16:16"). Remember I've always TEST what ever I'm posting as answer and this code was also a tested one and was working properly.